# Allow subclass in a class to access base class properties

Tags: python, class, oop

I'm trying to get my head around classes in Python and wonder if someone could help me solve the following problem please?

I have a base class which I intend to contain all information about a numerical simulation and the results of the simulation once run. However I also have routines that can output the simulation data to a file for manipulation at a later date.

Therefore, I want to write my code which processes and plots the simulation data in a separate class to the main simulation class (and in a separate .py file for neatness). This plotting class can then have two initialisation options: either being used to process data in a currently existing instance of the main simulation class, or to load the simulation data from a file ready for processing.

For the former case, the plotting class should be initialised as, say: simulation.plot = Plotter() and then have access to all the properties of the main simulation class. However I can't work out how to allow this subclass to have access to all the base class's properties.

A basic example showing my scenario and problem is:

```
class SimClass(object):
    def __init__(self, param1):
        self.param1 = param1
        # and many other parameters

    def run(self):
        # code to run the simulation
        self.results = results

        # initialise plotter as subclass
        self.plot = SimPlot()

class SimPlot(object):
    def init_from_saved_data(self, file_path):
        self.results = code_to_load_data_from_file

    def init_from_existing_sim(self):
        pass  #not sure how to do this        

    def plot1(self):
        plot(self.results[:,0], self.param1 * self.results[:,1]
```

And for the case where the Plotting code runs on existing sim object, the usage would be:

```
sim = SimClass(param1 = 5)
sim.run()
sim.plot1()
```

Any suggestions welcomed please (or even just to point out the terms I may have mis-used above regarding classes and OOP generally).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you simply need to have access to the SimClass instance in SimPlot.

You want something like this:

```
class SimClass(object):
    def run(self):
        self.results = ...
        self.plot = SimPlot(self)

class SimPlot(object):
    def __init__(self, simclass):
        self.simclass = simclass

    def plot1(self):
        # access simclass' attribute(s)
        self.simclass.results

sim = SimClass()
sim.run()
sim.plot.plot1()
```

(Updated per your comment)

Comment: Thanks, although this is kind of the inverse as what I'm intending. I want to do sim = SimClass(). Then sim.plot = SimPlot(), and then call my various processing scripts by doing sim.plot.plot1(). i.e. plot1 is a function of SimPlot() not SimClass()

Comment: I updated the answer.. a stylistic note: usually the class would be called just Sim or Simulation, not SimClass (since it's already known it's a class).

Answer (score 1):

You haven't got a base class and a subclass here, you've got two completely separate classes with no relationship between them. In order for SimPlot to be a subclass of SimClass, you need to declare it as such:

```
class SimPlot(SimClass):
    ...
```

Now any instance of SimPlot *automatically* has access to all its parent class's properties.

Comment: Ok, although won't this automatically initialise the SimClass, when what I need are the parameters which have been written to the already-initialised SimClass after having executed sim.run()?

Comment: @IanRoberts: Then make the `__init__()` constructor for the `SimPlot` subclass have an argument that is an already-initialized `SimClass` object -- or pass all the arguments to create one to it and initialize in the method.